# Changing instance variable in Python also changes original list

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, instance, instance-variables

Here is my code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x     = x
        self.y     = y

    def func(self):
        self.x[0] -= 1
        self.y    -= 1


x = [10]
y = 10



a = Foo(x, y)
a.func()

print(x, y)
```

Output is `([9], 10)`. Why does passing a list to an instance variable and then changing the instance variable also change the original list, but not the original integer?

How do you pass a list to an instance variable in Python, and then change the instance variable without affecting the original list?

Comment: Have a quick guide to Python variables and assignment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Also, you might think you're on Python 3, but that `print` output says you're not. (Python 3 would have printed `[9] 10`.)

Comment: Thank you, this helped! self.x = list(x) solved it

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because lists are mutable, while integers are immutable. Once you make a change to a list, the same list is returned. Once you change an integer, a "copy" of the integer is returned. So `func` is changing the `x`, but creating a new `y`

Answer (score 0):

The list is a mutable object; the assignment copies the reference, so that when you change the value of one element, you change the original object.

An integer is not mutable; when you change the value, Python changes the reference to a new object with the new value.  `self.y` does not refer to the same object as y any more.